# how to convert a binary number into a string

Tags: string, rust, binary, byte, digits

Would anyone know how to convert a binary number into a string that represents its digits ?

```
let  s: u32 = 0b00100000001011001100001101110001110000110010110011100000;
```

I need study different parts of this binary number by cuting it into pieces (ex first 5 digits, then digit 6 to 15, etc...).

In order to do so, I'm thinking using string slices but first I need to convert the binary number into a string ( "00100000010110011...").

Thank you !

Comment: First 5 binary digits: `s & 0x1F`, digits 6 to 15: `(s >> 6) & 0x3FF`

Comment: Note that your example number does not fit in a `u32`.

Comment: I feel this question is a special case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277050/is-there-a-built-in-function-that-converts-a-number-to-a-string-in-any-base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use binary format:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s: u64 = 0b00100000001011001100001101110001110000110010110011100000u64;
    let s_str: String = format!("{s:b}");
    println!("{s_str}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=98d4660a1906d580fc79ebd51ec1caf2)